# How to troubleshoot Errno 13 Permission Denied on a remote computer?

Tags: python, bots, telegram, remote-server, rdp

So I've been trying to use a python script to monitor my RDP server via telegram bot but there is a problem. The program doesn't have access for the screenshot output folder so the bot couldn't send the screenshot. Since the compiler gave me Errno 13 Permission Denied ([click here to see the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kfMR.jpg)), I thought that the problem is the permission. I tried to give my RDP user permission to that folder with Icacls /grant command, running the compiler as administrator, also manually editing the output folder permission via properties but nothing seems to work.

Here is my code:

```
import sys
import time
import telepot
import pyautogui
from telepot.loop import MessageLoop
from tokens import *

class MyBot(telepot.Bot):
  def init(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyBot, self).init(*args, **kwargs)
    self.answerer = telepot.helper.Answerer(self)
    self._message_with_inline_keyboard = None
    
  def on_chat_message(self, msg):
    content_type, chat_type, chat_id = telepot.glance(msg)
  
    if chat_id in adminId:
      if content_type == 'text':
        while msg['text'] == '/capture':
          bot.sendChatAction(chat_id, 'typing')
          bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Capturing image")
          self.capture_img()
          bot.sendPhoto(chat_id, photo=open('C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\bot', 'rb'))
          time.sleep(3600)
    
    else:
      bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Not admin")
  def capture_img(self):
    pic = pyautogui.screenshot()
    pic.save('C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\bot\\img\\screenshot.png')
    return
  
TOKEN = telegrambot

bot = MyBot(TOKEN)
MessageLoop(bot).run_as_thread()

while 1:
  time.sleep(5)
```

Does anyone know what should I do to fix this? Thanks for the respond

Comment: Why do you even have to write it to the disk…?

Answer (score 0):

Is `C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\bot` a folder instead of a file?

You can confirm this by adding something like

```
import os
...
photo_path = 'C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\bot'
assert os.path.isfile(photo_path)
bot.sendPhoto(chat_id, ...
...
```